# Crash happens on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

So my app was sent in and rejected. They said it crashed on iOS 5. I'm still pretty new to iPhone programming and I'm having difficulty reading the crash logs they sent. The said this along with the crash logs.

> We found that your app crashed on iPhone 4 running iOS 5, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Your app crashedon both Wi-Fi and cellular networks on launch.

If you can give me any help guiding me in the direction of where to look. Or how to be able to read one of these I would appreciate it. Anything but Apples explanation of how to read these. I found their explanation more confusing.

Here are the crash logs:

```
Incident Identifier: 797ABD0E-0C64-41C9-9A65-2605C0EC959E
CrashReporter Key:   4ac5bad7693f6fffd20e043218a547ee54565eb3
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         Stoners Handbook [688]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/D5E8D62A-D69D-4764-BB2A-0FA692427030/Stoners Handbook.app/Stoners Handbook
Identifier:      Stoners Handbook
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-10-10 11:04:14.776 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x30fee8bf 0x381931e5 0x30fee7b9 0x30fee7db 0x331fc747 0x331fdbb9 0x33136a45 0x32fc0227 0x32fba313 0x32f88921 0x32f883bf 0x32f87d2d 0x33b73e13 0x30fc2553 0x30fc24f5 0x30fc1343 0x30f444dd 0x30f443a5 0x32fb9457 0x32fb6743 0x2231 0x21c8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x322d332c 0x322c2000 + 70444
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x367c9f54 0x3677c000 + 319316
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x367c2fe4 0x3677c000 + 290788
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x31c8bf64 0x31c85000 + 28516
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x31c89346 0x31c85000 + 17222
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x381932dc 0x3818a000 + 37596
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x31c893be 0x31c85000 + 17342
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x31c8944a 0x31c85000 + 17482
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x31c8a81e 0x31c85000 + 22558
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3819322e 0x3818a000 + 37422
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30f4453e 0x30f35000 + 62782
11  CoreFoundation                  0x30f4439e 0x30f35000 + 62366
12  UIKit                           0x32fb9450 0x32f85000 + 214096
13  UIKit                           0x32fb673c 0x32f85000 + 202556
14  Stoners Handbook                0x0000222a 0x1000 + 4650
15  Stoners Handbook                0x000021c0 0x1000 + 4544

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x322c33b4 0x322c2000 + 5044
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x32a17e78 0x32a0b000 + 52856
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x32a17b96 0x32a0b000 + 52118

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x322d3cd4 0x322c2000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3678630a 0x3677c000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3678609c 0x3677c000 + 41116

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x322d3cd4 0x322c2000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3678630a 0x3677c000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3678609c 0x3677c000 + 41116

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x322c3010 0x322c2000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x322c3206 0x322c2000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30fc241c 0x30f35000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30fc1154 0x30f35000 + 573780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30f444d6 0x30f35000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30f4439e 0x30f35000 + 62366
6   WebCore                         0x377d8128 0x37730000 + 688424
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3678bc16 0x3677c000 + 64534
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3678bad0 0x3677c000 + 64208

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3f7b9ce8      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdffa48
    r8: 0x3ed5ddec    r9: 0x31c8ca4a     r10: 0x00122eb0     r11: 0x0011d790
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdffa3c      lr: 0x367c9f5b      pc: 0x322d332c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x5dfff +Stoners Handbook armv7  <94612993644a31d7804ebbd8a49b509b> /var/mobile/Applications/D5E8D62A-D69D-4764-BB2A-0FA692427030/Stoners Handbook.app/Stoners Handbook
0x2fe8d000 - 0x2feaefff  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3057c000 - 0x3057cfff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x30598000 - 0x305ddfff  GeoServices armv7  <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x30626000 - 0x3063bfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <2e35ec83cc823bbebf107dc4867e61d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3063f000 - 0x3064efff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x3080d000 - 0x30810fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <48fe217ed667308bb9413c11f5b5b31d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x30814000 - 0x309d0fff  ImageIO armv7  <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x309d1000 - 0x30aabfff  vImage armv7  <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30dbc000 - 0x30f01fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <649b7b4a430a340b8c2b85c6fb4e1369> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x30f09000 - 0x30f09fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x30f0e000 - 0x30f31fff  Bom armv7  <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30f35000 - 0x3104cfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a2dbc131fdc0364e822339ca2926b6e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x31095000 - 0x31096fff  DataMigration armv7  <4179a9f217a8300d93c14b6fd87e5c31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x31097000 - 0x310e0fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x310e1000 - 0x310e2fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <77460820431837d68f19c81d53b6ca83> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x310e3000 - 0x3115cfff  ProofReader armv7  <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x317bb000 - 0x317d1fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <ff80b6648c24360583e5e624efda4815> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3199c000 - 0x319bcfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x319bd000 - 0x319dcfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <17803796ac1d31bdab85e651a74d5e0d> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31bff000 - 0x31c05fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <19d7596821403d998017f03678d40514> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x31c18000 - 0x31c3bfff  PrintKit armv7  <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31c49000 - 0x31c84fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <1f70c1e94e333f0bb0866143b2abb0a7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31c85000 - 0x31c8cfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x31fca000 - 0x31fd0fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <18472eec0dfa3aa993f4ae7f34ec5c52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x32240000 - 0x32241fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3227f000 - 0x322bcfff  IOKit armv7  <284ee3241c4a3b43b81b9ff514997013> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x322c2000 - 0x322d8fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <ac287acb68d032118cd824a51011638d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x32340000 - 0x32389fff  CoreMedia armv7  <16e247e3f4a43fc5a72695092cf8ba96> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3269b000 - 0x3278bfff  QuartzCore armv7  <c77ceeffd75e3bcc9df3bbe91e2dac98> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x328e4000 - 0x329d2fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <0f52661fd7af3a448b95f8d93d20f3f7> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x32a0b000 - 0x32a21fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <86ed1499ae1e3f5ba389e657f6a23ced> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x32b01000 - 0x32b4afff  AddressBook armv7  <9ac3368232663b5786382e33c3773678> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x32b4b000 - 0x32b4bfff  vecLib armv7  <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32b4c000 - 0x32b51fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <11ce894432a73b9485cce6f5b1ea6488> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x32c36000 - 0x32c36fff  Accelerate armv7  <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x32d42000 - 0x32d85fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x32da2000 - 0x32e12fff  CoreImage armv7  <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x32eb7000 - 0x32ebafff  CoreTime armv7  <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x32ee1000 - 0x32ee5fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x32ee6000 - 0x32efcfff  EAP8021X armv7  <3f7bd850face343495b2c542ef63d44d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x32efd000 - 0x32f7cfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <cdd807e0d8523476b666a9dc63750bb7> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x32f85000 - 0x3341efff  UIKit armv7  <87348d5d0d043aa095840765b6d73999> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3341f000 - 0x33423fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x336d2000 - 0x336defff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x336e3000 - 0x336e3fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x33712000 - 0x33769fff  CoreAudio armv7  <d0d388a7373036a08561809242f5a5f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33779000 - 0x33785fff  CoreVideo armv7  <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3389a000 - 0x3396afff  WebKit armv7  <b79a797a66723db89d6c2f89c0925cf8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x33980000 - 0x33984fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <607095842baf3c41be3127ed773582ea> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3398d000 - 0x33b6afff  AudioToolbox armv7  <59dd50551a893636b94bf4505a62ef97> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x33b6b000 - 0x33b6bfff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x33b6c000 - 0x33b6efff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x33b6f000 - 0x33b7afff  GraphicsServices armv7  <08bfaa5766853884a09cd70f5ae37017> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33f55000 - 0x34002fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x34003000 - 0x3401cfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ad22ea5ee99a358691f9820e62c85058> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3401d000 - 0x34023fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <4e3671438f71326bbc507cb197a31322> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x343c5000 - 0x34909fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x34cbd000 - 0x34f7efff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x35210000 - 0x3521ffff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <083fb830455f3cd0869bf54bfd91108c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x35220000 - 0x3526bfff  CoreLocation armv7  <77f81f93c6483079b547b3552b0247d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x35602000 - 0x35613fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <637167f4fa5c3cee99418295843e1580> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x35614000 - 0x356befff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x356e0000 - 0x356eafff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x356f5000 - 0x356fbfff  MobileIcons armv7  <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x356fc000 - 0x35706fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x35707000 - 0x3570efff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <f6d1bb9e4b60392f834d4e0ee35105cc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x357e9000 - 0x3580efff  OpenCL armv7  <051a834ba5583f47876f0c8b9a1e3dda> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x35949000 - 0x3595dfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <47b0ba3bcfd230a192119445de86cef1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x35b2a000 - 0x35b63fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35b64000 - 0x35b68fff  IOSurface armv7  <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35b69000 - 0x35b6efff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <49003f67c59730c9ac9c499517a3bb8b> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x35b7a000 - 0x35baffff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <68dbad71a3cc32e5941ad70820f88caa> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x35bb0000 - 0x35bbcfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <8e4095644cc33c97aa5f9f0620387f88> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x35cb8000 - 0x35cb9fff  CoreSurface armv7  <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x35cd3000 - 0x35cd7fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x35cde000 - 0x35d2ffff  CoreText armv7  <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x35e8d000 - 0x35e95fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3618f000 - 0x3619cfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x361c8000 - 0x361cafff  MobileInstallation armv7  <4c0648df13af341e88ddca80be687794> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x361e4000 - 0x361e5fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x36209000 - 0x3620afff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <1dadb6191d1835e5b078594218ce14f3> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x36228000 - 0x362fffff  CFNetwork armv7  <794a80e086d23041bfdec139b01e80a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36349000 - 0x3634afff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x36597000 - 0x366e0fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3677c000 - 0x36809fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <2eb267ac3b5e32b0a43a61ccb98e6dd1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x36913000 - 0x3691afff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <00599097fff03d02896974966dee6dda> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x369e7000 - 0x36a27fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x36a36000 - 0x36a3afff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x36ab9000 - 0x36b03fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x36b12000 - 0x36b1dfff  AccountSettings armv7  <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x36b1e000 - 0x36b2ffff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <2306f236fe113baba3934f1884d36a47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36b56000 - 0x36b9afff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <e05a113469ed345f98f306965abb30dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x36b9b000 - 0x36becfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x36da6000 - 0x36dc3fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <8e5dd82833293382a08f11517e9dcb9b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x36e65000 - 0x36e65fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x36e87000 - 0x36ed0fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <80836b34a3ef389d82f0fa55cadccc61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x36ed3000 - 0x36f0afff  Security armv7  <195ed72ea7583470958d72652bd84f03> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x37003000 - 0x37009fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <8d5c3270e68e3dbbb2a72efd71314bf6> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3711f000 - 0x37122fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x37143000 - 0x37146fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <d7f346d1c62d35b18fec919efc67eb84> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x372a6000 - 0x372e2fff  AppSupport armv7  <202262953e2d343cbf489fe1e308dba4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x37327000 - 0x37371fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <7cb3680db3bb36a0b59b6d8e8cecf374> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x37372000 - 0x3737bfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <bf524f1f6e8237369795867c7e2b4e67> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x373aa000 - 0x374cefff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <322e347adc08308ca55fc7de9598248c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x37730000 - 0x37ee7fff  WebCore armv7  <5a60e1e3f68331e5b426dd4dfeb3def8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x37ff0000 - 0x3816efff  Foundation armv7  <c1afe35de1f63b0db5b7ced0dec7163f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3816f000 - 0x38185fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x38186000 - 0x38189fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3818a000 - 0x38250fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <d503b4ad04313023bbe76ededd30ed70> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x38251000 - 0x38260fff  OpenGLES armv7  <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
```

Comment: *Stoners Handbook* - Interesting )

Comment: @chown Ya my Android app for iPhone

Comment: Even if you fix your bug, your app will probably get rejected because of this guideline: "Apps that solicit, promote, or encourage criminal or clearly reckless behavior will be rejected".

Comment: @CanSpice I realize that, but they have quite a few marijuana apps on their market. So I'll just cut out everything that would make it rejected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to "symbolicate" the crash report to figure out where in your source code the crash occurred.  See http://aasims.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/how-to-symbolicate-iphone-crash-reports/ for an example of how to do this.